# what are advantages of mootools over jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

In short notice this can be a fairly stupid question. But I still would to know what are the advantages/disadvantages of using MooTools JS compared to jQuery?

Personally I find jQuery uses way shorter syntaxes but MooTools can handle heavy loads. So its win/loose situation. So can some one provided some info which one of this Library's would be better with high AJAX end web app?

Comment: AJAX is ajax no matter which way you use it they both take advantage of the same browser APIs.  I doubt there is any speed difference at all between jQuery and Mootols.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good comparison: http://jqueryvsmootools.com/ (found by doing a simple google search :) )

Comment: That article was written in May of 2009. There have been a lot of changes to the libraries since then.

Comment: While that might be true, if you read the article carefully, it bases the comparison largely on the difference in Mootools' & JQuery's ideologies, or mission statements, so to speak. If you go to their respective sites, you'll see that the ideologies are still the same. And being an avid JQuery user I completely believe that it is true to it's mission statement. So, it might be true that the article is from 2009 and that there may have been a lot of library changes, but the crux of the technologies will still be the same.